Implementing Drag-and-Drop Window Positioning on a Wall Using React Three.js
I am planning to create a window on a wall.
The position of the window can be controlled using drag and drop.
The window should not be draggable beyond the boundaries of the wall (e.g., when the window’s position exceeds the wall’s length).
Additionally, the window must always remain within the wall’s dimensions.
I am unsure how to implement this functionality using React and Three.js.
If you have example code, Please provide me.
https://shedview.moderngardenrooms.com/
This is the website that shows me the results I want.
Thank you.
I am unsure how to implement this functionality using React and Three.js.
